# Is Street fighter a missable achievement?

Tags: achievements, punch-club

Is the achievement "Street Fighter" missable in the game punch club? I have become a professional fighter, and now if I speak to Tyler, the option to "test myself" on at the bar doesn't allow me to fight, instead the dialogue ends with him calling me "professional slimeball". Is it still possible for me to get this achievement?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to start a new game and get it?

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe Yes, but that makes it a missable achievement. I was wondering if there is something that might happen in the future to allow me to fight on the street again.